# optimization flag '-falign-functions=8' is not supported in Clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm-clang

We have a library that heavily uses function pointer, where assumed functions are aligned 8 bytes.

In GCC, there is `falign-functions` option to specify alignment of functions.

However in Clang, `falign-functions=<num>` option seems to be disabled compared to GCC.

Is there any alternative option to achieve this?

Without this feature, our program dies with segmentation fault.

Comment: What about -malign-functions=8 ?

Comment: @nos Sorry for very late response... Do you have any idea to brief check -malign-functions=8 is enabled? I still cannot isolate the problem that fails compilation of my project.